# Call a php function to echo in place

Tags: php

I have this code

```
$css=0;
    <?php
     echo "<div>";
  function style(){
       global $css;
    echo $css;
    }
        echo "</div>";
$css =5 ; style();
?>
```

what i want to happen is this

```
<div>5</div>
```

and what really happens is

```
<div></div>5
```

I need to declare the value of the variable then go back and echo it in the same place it intended to be in, and I can't change the order due to many reasons in the code structure .

UPDATE :: after reading all the answers it seems i wasn't clear enough .

```
<html>
<?php $css=0; ?>
<div id="<?php echo $css ?>"></div>
<div id ="K"></div>

<?php
$css=5;
?>

</html>
```

this is the situation

1- i can not declare $css before the echo.

2- i can not reposition anything from this structure .

3- i can not put #K after the declaring of the $css .

what i really need a way to put the value inside the variable and let echo where it's .

any ideas ?

Comment: You call the style() function after your `echo "<div>"` and `echo "</div>"`
You should put `echo "<div>".$css."</div>"` in your function or call function before the `echo "</div>"`

Comment: __Define__ your function ___before___ echoing the div; __call__ the function ___inside___ the echoed div

Comment: what is the reason behind this logic? you can pass value 5 in function param best way

Comment: php cannot time travel....

Comment: did you not try the probable JS solution below? http://stackoverflow.com/a/34398934/

Comment: Maybe use php ob_* function

Answer (score 2):

you can try this as well using js

```
<?php

  $css=0; 
  echo "<div id='tt'>"; 
  /*function style(){global $css; echo $css;}*/
  echo "</div>";

  $css =5 ;
  echo "<script>";
  echo "document.getElementById('tt').innerHTML = $css";
  echo "</script>";
  ?>
```

Comment: Java script or Jquery is going to be the only way to accomplish this. If you are going to change the ID of the DIV, then the getElementById function won't work. Use a: data- ,tag to select the correct element and then you can assign the id property of the element(as in your update to the question)

Comment: [It seems that we/I have fallen onto deaf ears...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398639/call-a-php-function-to-echo-in-place#comment56539990_34398639).

Answer (score 0):

Your function is run when you call it, and as it is called below the  you get the expected 5.

To fix this:

```
echo "<div>";
style();
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: can't do this . 
need to call the style after all divs are echo ed .

Comment: Why, can you explain?

Comment: i updated the question if you want to look again. 
i 'm in a situation where there are divs that needs to be echo ed first after that i can do some calculations and come up with the value i need to be in the $css variable , this $css variable can't be echoed after the divs IT MUST be before them so i should go back and echo it before them .

Comment: Then you have to use Javascript/Jquery. I do not see another possibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    echo "<div>";
        function style() {
            global $css;
            echo $css;
        }
    $css =5 ;
    style();
    echo "</div>";
?>
```

or simply:

```
<?php
    function style() {
        global $css;
        echo $css;
    }

    $css = 5;
    echo "<div>" . style() . "</div>";
?>
```

Previously, you well calling the function to echo out the variable after closing the div.

Comment: you're welcome. I deleted my comment when I noticed you added an explanation ;-)

Comment: can't do both 
can't  rearrange the order there's other divs after the first one and the $css declaring need to be the statement written . 
for the "or simply" solution , can't declare $css value before echo ing .

Comment: @moawaya: can you post your actual code? I don't see any impossibility in the one you have posted with your question. BTW I'm sorry as the real problem wasn't clear in the question when you just posted it.